# in FastAPI, can not use resolver async await

Tags: graphene-python, fastapi

I am using graphene with the fastapi but can not get a simple async resolver working. any help is appreciated.

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    hello = graphene.String(name=graphene.String(default_value=""))

    async def resolve_hello(self, info, name):
      image_url = "my_url"
      async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(image_url)
        # img_bytes = await get_bytes(request.query_params["url"])
        // do stuff
```

and the error is

```
{
  "data": {
    "hello": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0'."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are you importing httpx ? The problem seems to be the instantiation is not using the right event loop

Comment: ah, can you point me to some documentation or an example of the right event loop?

Comment: Could it also be that request is not imported in an async manner? Sorry but with such a little example I can't help. On my computer I have an example with httpx that gets the page from google.com and it works (even in routers)

Comment: i have the whole project here, which is quite small https://github.com/foobar8675/fastai-bite/tree/async. however, if you have an example of your code, that would be super helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Graphene (2) is not using AsyncioExecutor anymore

```python
    app = FastAPI()
    app.add_route("/", GraphQLApp(schema=graphene.Schema(query=Query),
    executor_class=AsyncioExecutor))
```

I would recommand to use [Strawbery](https://strawberry.rocks/) or [starlette-graphene3](https://github.com/ciscorn/starlette-graphene3)
If you want to use pydantic

```
pip install starlette-graphene3
```

upgrade your pip if needed

```python
    import asyncio

    import graphene
    import pydantic
    from fastapi import FastAPI
    from starlette.applications import Starlette
    from starlette_graphene3 import GraphQLApp, make_graphiql_handler
    from graphene_pydantic import PydanticObjectType


    class PersonModel(pydantic.BaseModel):
        first_name: str
        last_name: str


    class Person(PydanticObjectType):
        class Meta:
            model = PersonModel


    async def wait_for_me(wo):
        return wo

    class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
        people = graphene.List(Person)

        async def resolve_people(root, info):
            mmd = await wait_for_me("jose")
            return [PersonModel(first_name=mmd, last_name="Smith")]


    class Subscription(graphene.ObjectType):
        count = graphene.Int(upto=graphene.Int())

        async def subscribe_count(root, info, upto=3):
            for i in range(upto):
                yield i
                # await asyncio.sleep(1)


    app = FastAPI()


    @app.get("/hello")
    def read_root():
        return {"Hello": "World"}



    schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, subscription=Subscription)


    app.mount("/", GraphQLApp(schema, on_get=make_graphiql_handler()))  # Graphiql IDE
    # app.mount("/", GraphQLApp(schema, on_get=make_playground_handler()))  # Playground IDE
    # app.mount("/", GraphQLApp(schema)) # no IDE
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

When you add the GraphQL endpoint to the `app` object, replace it with

```
app = FastAPI()
app.add_route("/", GraphQLApp(schema=graphene.Schema(query=Query),
    executor_class=AsyncioExecutor))
```

**FULL ANSWER**

Ok, so I found your problem after checking with the docs and comparing them with your code.

It's not a problem with httpx, instead the problem is with how you use GraphQL.

As you can see in [Fastapi Docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/graphql/#add-starlettes-graphqlapp), the `resolve_hello` function is declared with a traditional `def` instead of `async def`. This makes a difference for the GraphQL engine when running because it calls the function, but does not await it, instead, it gets the coroutine object and goes on with returning the result. Since the result is a coroutine it does not work and throws the exception you posted. The solution lays in the [Starlette Docs](https://www.starlette.io/graphql/#sync-or-async-executors), which passes as parameter the `asyncio` engine for running `async` GraphQL queries.

It's tricky, because fastAPI is based on Starlette, so you have to read both docs in case you need something.

Let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: that is awesome. thank you. it seems maybe just using starlette by itself and importing pedantic might be easier than using fastapi for graphql. do you have an opinion?

Comment: Personally, I don't use graphql, so I can't tell exactly. Starlette is more raw, while fastapi glues together several tools like starlette and pydantic. Key differences are explained at https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/alternatives/#starlette but my advice, especially for a new user, is to try to keep it simple and follow the patterns by using the complete systems available. Once you'll have reached the necessary experience, start digging deeper and using the raw tools. Learn how to drive first, then build a car yourself

Comment: AsyncioExecutor is not in Graphene anymore, this answer obsolete unfortunately

Comment: @PekoChan can you provide more information about it? A link or something. I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: AsyncioExecutor will return an ModuleNotFoundError Exception, so better use https://github.com/ciscorn/starlette-graphene3 it works also with graphene-pydantic too @Isabi